# How do I prefill the origin and destination of a mapbox directions api?

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Display driving directions</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.47.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.47.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v3.1.3/mapbox-gl-directions.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v3.1.3/mapbox-gl-directions.css' type='text/css' />
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYndhZGFtc29uIiwiYSI6ImNqajZhNm1idDFzMjIza3A2Y3ZmdDV6YWYifQ.9NhptR7a9D0hzWXR51y_9w';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-79.4512, 43.6568],
    zoom: 13
});

map.addControl(new MapboxDirections({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
}), 'top-left');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This gives me a nice map with driving directions but I want to prefill the "starting place" and "destination" in the rendered map. How do I do that via javascript so the user doesn't have to enter their information twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the [`setOrigin`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md#setorigin) and [`setDestination`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md#setdestination) methods from the [`MapboxDirections API`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md):

```
map.on('load', function() {
  var directions = new MapboxDirections({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
  });
  map.addControl(directions, 'top-left');

  directions.setOrigin('Brockton Avenue, Toronto');
  directions.setDestination('East York Avenue, Toronto');
});
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/me3kj9td/ ]